# How to create a trigger that generate a random specific output to insert into a table in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trigger, normalization, default-value

I have an account table which is laid out in 3NF:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    account_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_id INT NOT NULL,
    account_type_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    is_active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    opening_balance DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 51,
    account_number INT(8) NOT NULL,
    sort_code VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    created_date DATE DEFAULT now(),
    branch_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id),
    UNIQUE(sort_code, account_number)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

However, I want to know if there is a way to create a trigger that upon inserting into this table a unique sort_code and account_number can be generated. The account number should just be a unique 8 digit, however, the first 3 digits will contain the id of branch_id from a separate branch table, e.g an account belonging to branch_id 700 should have an account number starting with 700. And sort code should have this format "XX-XX-XX" where the X's numbers and this should also be checked to be unique. Is it possible to make a trigger to do this in MySQL/mariadb?

Comment: It is certainly possible. What's your real question?

Comment: Of course this everything is possible. But the task itself is problematic - in theory you may reach the state when there is no value that matches your conditions and is not present in the table already...

Comment: @mustaccio what do you mean,ive asked my question above how to geenrate a unique account number and sort code, in the format mentioned above, within a transaction, after inserting into the account table.

Comment: Assuming this is for the UK, the bank and branch are encoded in the sort code, not the account number. See e.g. the [explanation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_code).

Comment: @dbdemon so is the account number is a random unqiue 8 digit code?

Comment: I think the combination of sort code + account number is meant to be unique, but the account number itself is not necessarily unique. See e.g. [this news story in the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2005/nov/05/accounts.saving).

Comment: @dbdemon e.g the format of the sort code is XXYYZZ where XX = 55 (the bank code for our bank),
YY = random number pair, and ZZ = branch id. Is this the correct understanding? then account number is just 8 random numbers? thank

Comment: I don't think two digits are not enough to identify the branch for larger banks. E.g. Barclays has more than 1,600 branches in the UK according to Wikipedia.

Comment: @dbdemon so XX-YY-ZZ use YY AND ZZ for branch?

Comment: That is probably the wrong approach.  Instead, store the raw pieces, then build the desired combo on the fly.  A `GENERATED VIRTUAL` column may assist in that.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more than one way to do this, but here is one idea.

You don't have to use triggers.

Use [MariaDB sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-sequence/) to generate unique numbers - assuming it's OK that the numbers are created sequentially.

Assuming you are designing a system for one particular bank, and the digits in the sort code are used to identify the bank and branch, then:

- The first two digits of the sort code identifies the bank and will always be the same, so you don't need to store these.
- Put the branch digits in the same column as the account number digits.
- Create one sequence per branch where you specify a unique range for each, defined by the sequence's `MINVALUE` and `MAXVALUE`.
- For display purposes, you can decode into sort code and account number by using [generated columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/).

**Basic example code for sequences**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_branch_1 
  MINVALUE 100000000 
  MAXVALUE 199999999 
  START WITH 100000000 
  INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_branch_2
  MINVALUE 200000000 
  MAXVALUE 299999999 
  START WITH 200000000 
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

And so on.

At the time of creating an account you presumably know which branch it's for, so:

```
INSERT INTO account(customer_id, account_type_id, ... unique_account_number, ...)
  VALUES (416, 2, ..., NEXTVAL(seq_branch_2), ...);
```

Comment: Thank you, can you give some brief template code for this so I can get a better understanding of what you mean.

Comment: @Mj_ does that help?

Comment: thank you! I last question regarding the sort code , so did you say sort code first pair should be the bank code, then the 2nd 2 pairs are the branch id?

Comment: @Mj_ yes, that is my understanding. Although (speculating here) it's possible this varies between banks. E.g. an Internet-only bank with no physical branches might want to use all those digits to identify the account instead. That said, who needs that many digits? I don't know.